# Ruby array validate based on join table foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a data model that looks like so;

```
class Tran < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :buyer
validates :buyer_id, presence: true

belongs_to :seller
validates :seller_id, presence: true

end

class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :trans
has_many :buyers, through: :trans
validates :seller_id, presence: true

end

class Buyer < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :trans, :foreign_key => "buyer_id"
has_many :sellers, through: :trans
validates :buyer_id, presence: true

end
```

And then on each Seller page I have the following code that I can successfully give a list of the seller's top Buyers descending based on their total spend.

```
<ol>
  <% @seller.buyers.uniq{|t| t.buyer_id }.sort_by {|su| su.trans.sum(:sum)}.reverse.each do |su| %>
  <li><%= su.name %> <%= su.trans.sum(:sum) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ol>
```

This code works in that it validates only Buyers that that have bought a product from the Seller, however it does not currently validate only the Trans made with the Seller (e.g. pulls in data between ALL the Sellers).

I have tried putting in a second validation around seller.id too, but unsure how to it.

Does anyone have a solution?

So essentially the list needs to validate that on the Tran, both the seller_id is owned by the Seller, plus present in the Trans join table, and that it also pulls in the buyer_id, but only the transactions that both supplier_id and buyer_id are present.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the unwanted code..its just pure `has many through association`...it should be

```
class Buyer< ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :trans
  has_many :sellers, through: :trans
  validates_presence_of :sellers
  ##or you can use blocks also such as below for validation(not null)
  has_many :sellers,through :trans,:reject_if => proc { |a| a['name'].blank? }


end 

 class Tran< ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :buyers
  belongs_to :sellers

 end


 class Seller< ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :trans 
   has_many :buyers, through: :trans
   validates_presence_of :buyers

 end

###to get all sellers of a buyer
@buyer.sellers
##to get all buyers from a seller
@seller.buyers
```

To make this work..you need to have three migration files including trans table with just two column-buyer_id and seller_id which will prevent any fallback in joins between buyer/seller and hence you dont need to validate the buyer_id/seller_id

```
class CreateBuyersSellersTrans < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change     
    create_table :buyers do |t|
      ##ensures uniqueness
       t.string :name, unique: true 
       t.timestamps
    end 

    create_table :sellers do |t|
     ##ensures uniqueness
       t.string :name, unique: true 
       t.timestamps
     end  

    create_table :trans do |t|
       t.belongs_to :buyer 
       t.belongs_to :seller           t.timestamps 
    end  
  end
end
```

in your controller

```
 #get all uniq buyers of a seller in array format removing empty even if exits
@sellers=@seller.buyers.flatten.compact.uniq.delete_if(&:blank?)
```

in your view

```
<ol>
  <% @sellers.sort_by {|su| su.trans.sum(:sum)}.reverse.each do |su| %>
  <li><%= su.name %> <%= su.trans.sum(:sum) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks, struggling to make it work - I'll keep at it!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than getting the Seller and the Seller's Buyers, and then the Buyer's Trans, how about getting the Seller and the Seller's Trans(es), and then the Buyer's information from each Seller's Trans?